# Unable to strip a stubborn space from a Ruby string (Nokogiri is involved)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse an HTML document. A representation of the source code which this question is based upon follows:

```
<td width='400' valign=top>
  <b><u>Jenny ID:</u>&nbsp;8675309</b><br />
        Name of Place<br />
        Street Address<br />
        City, State, Zip<br />
        Contact: Jenny Jenny<br />
        Phone: 867-5309<br />
        Fax: 
</td>
```

I'm using a couple delimiters to retrieve the text between `Jenny ID:` and `Name of Place`. Using `#strip`, I'm unable to strip out the leading space.

```
 > returned_value.inspect
=> " 8675309\r\n                  "
 > returned_value.strip
=> " 8675309"
```

If I use a test string, `#strip` does indeed remove the leading and trailing white space(s).

```
 > test_string = " 11111 "
 > test_tring.strip
=> "11111"
```

How can I completely strip out this leading space? I suspect it's the `&nbsp` but I cannot rid myself of it.

I promise I'm not this dumb in real life, but this problem is beating me down. It's merciless.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try " string ".chomp ? (it gets rids of the \n\r), then you can strip it. So: "".chomp.strip

Comment: Chomp does not work. The leading space still exists.

Comment: How did you get the content of the td? With the text method?

Comment: not pretty but you could use `returned_value.strip[1..-1]`

Comment: Im sorry i read wrongly, saw the \r\n. Maybe some encoding? Can you copy paste the string in IRB and does it give a same result?

Comment: @Rogier, I feel you're asking questions which I answered in my post. Calling `#strip` returns the string with a leading white space remaining content after `#strip`: `" 8675309"`.

Comment: If you have your HTML as a string, why not try to gsub('&nbsp;','') before you call Nokogiri on it?

Comment: @RailsFan - the HTML is a document and not a string.

Comment: I do not really understand what do you mean. Document is not a ruby type, String is, so you can use gsub on it. I meant only that. Even if you open an HTML file from your disk, you will get it as a string. eg. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-read
Anyway, it seems you have your answer

Comment: What I'm saying is that I'm parsing an HTML document, I just offered up the pertinent part for the sake of the question. Are you suggesting I parse the document beforehand, removing any occurrences of `&nbsp;`?

Comment: @RailsFan - I'm saying that I'm parsing a document. Yes, it's technically a "File" if we use Ruby syntax. I was trying to just use simple English. Here's a pastie of the pertinent parts of the script to illustrate what I attempted to explain (contains the accepted answer):  http://pastie.org/8970609

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thanks and sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to get the same error like you and created this example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = Nokogiri::HTML(<<-html
<td width='400' valign=top>
  <b><u>Jenny ID:</u>&nbsp;8675309</b><br />
        Name of Place<br />
        Street Address<br />
        City, State, Zip<br />
        Contact: Jenny Jenny<br />
        Phone: 867-5309<br />
        Fax: 
</td>
html
)

el = html.css('b').first
txt = el.content.split(':').last
puts txt    # ' 8675309'
p txt         #"\u00A08675309"
p txt.strip #"\u00A08675309"
```

The leading character is no space, but `\u00A0` (The Unicode Character ['NO-BREAK SPACE'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (U+00A0)). It seems `strip` does not remove it.

If you remove the no-break space explicit, you get the result you want. If you replace `\u00A0` with `' '` (a normal space), then you can remove the space with strip without removing it inside the string.

Code:

```
p txt.gsub("\u00A0", ' ').strip   #-> "8675309"
```

Alternative you can use (thanks to mu is too short)

```
p txt.gsub(/\p{Space}/, ' ').strip
```

This requires UTF-8 code. Without you may get an Encoding::CompatibilityError.

Comment: Does 'p txt' show these 'invisible' bytes? or did you printed them in a special way (since a normal string doesn't display unicode)?

Comment: Might be better off using `/\p{Space}/` to clean up the whitespace, that should catch all of the whitespace.

Comment: @rogier No, `p x` is the same as `puts x.inspect`. Normally I don't work in irb, so the `p` command is my shortcut to see the internal side of variables.

Comment: @knut muistooshort telling to write `txt.gsub(/\p{Space}/, '')`..I think.

Comment: I did indeed receive the Encoding::CompatiblityError. I'll stick with your original solution, @knut. Thanks much for the help, all! I did try my hand at inspecting each of the elements returned by Nokogiri, the answer was there. I just could not see it.